# Como crear un array de objeto en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, array, object

Originalmente tenia un array en el que iba haciendo un push del contenido de un campo de texto.

```
var arrayControl = [];

if(validar(tr)==true) {                 
    arrayControl.push(tr.find(".input-campo-id").val())
}
```

Ahora necesito agregar el contenido de otro campo de texto llamado ".input-campo-detalle" en la misma posición, es decir Pos[1] {"Id1" - "Detalle2"}, Pos[2] {"Id2" "Detalle2"}, etc.

Pensé en hacer un array dentro de otro array pero no se si es la forma más conveniente y como hacerlo.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola podrias hacer esto.

```
var arrayControl = [];
if (validar(tr)) {
   var objeto = {
      id: tr.find(".input-campo-id").val(),
      detalle: tr.find(".input-campo-detalle").val()
   };
   arrayControl.push(objeto);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!. ¿Ahora podria preguntarte como puedo recorrer ese array con un For y obtener el "id" y el "detalle" segun la posicion en la que me encuntro ?

Comment: Muy simple, lo debes hacer con un for, y la manera de acceder a los datos es arrayControl[indice].id.

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te dejo algunas formas de utilizar objetos que podrían servirte:

```
var myObject = new Object();
myObject.id = tr.find(".input-campo-id").val();
myObject.detalle = tr.find(".input-campo-detalle").val();
arrayControl.push(myObject);
```

---

```
var myObject = new Object();
myObject['id'] = tr.find(".input-campo-id").val();
myObject['detalle'] = tr.find(".input-campo-detalle").val();
arrayControl.push(myObject);
```

---

```
var myObject = {
    id: tr.find(".input-campo-id").val(),
    detalle: tr.find(".input-campo-detalle").val()
};
arrayControl.push(myObject);
```

En todo caso si necesitas más información puedes revisar el siguiente enlace: [Trabajando con objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos).

Saludos ;)